tensorflow convolve two 1D signals
I have two arrays and I can't figure out how to simply convolve them in tensorflow. In numpy I would do:
import numpy as np
from numpy import convolve

a=np.array([1,0,3])
b=np.array([-1,2])
convolve(a,b)

and the output is array([-1,  2, -3,  6]).
How can I do this in tensorflow? I tried this:
a=tf.constant([1,0,3])
b=tf.constant([-1,2])


tf.nn.convolution(a,b,strides=1)

But I get ValueError: `num_spatial_dims` must be 1, 2, or 3. Received: num_spatial_dims=-1.

Tensorflow does not have a full padding option like in numpy, so you'll have to add padding yourself:
a=tf.constant([1,0,3])
b=tf.constant([-1,2])
b=tf.reverse(b,axis=[0])
pad_add = len(b)-1

paddings = tf.constant([[pad_add,pad_add]])
a = tf.pad(a,paddings)

a=tf.reshape(a,(1,len(a),1))

b=tf.reshape(b,(len(b),1,1))

output =tf.nn.convolution(input = a, filters = b)
print(output.numpy().flatten())

This gives:[-1  2 -3  6]
